# Tuning ReactiveElasticsearchClient due to ReadTimeoutException

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-webclient

We've been experimenting around with the `ReactiveElasticsearchRepository` however we're running into issues when the service remains idle for several hours and you attempt to retrieve data from Elastic Search that it times out.

What we're seeing when making those first few requests is:

```
2019-11-06 17:31:35.858  WARN [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0x8cf5e94d, L:/192.168.1.100:60745 - R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null
```

When I enable `DEBUG` for `reactor.netty`, I can see that it goes through the motions of trying each connection in the pool:

```
2019-11-06 17:31:30.841 DEBUG [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x8cf5e94d, L:/192.168.1.100:60745 - R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] Channel acquired, now 1 active connections and 2 inactive connections
2019-11-06 17:31:35.858  WARN [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0x8cf5e94d, L:/192.168.1.100:60745 - R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null

2019-11-06 17:31:35.881 DEBUG [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x8cf5e94d, L:/192.168.1.100:60745 ! R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] Releasing channel
2019-11-06 17:31:35.891 DEBUG [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x8cf5e94d, L:/1192.168.1.100:60745 ! R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 2 inactive connections
2019-11-06 17:32:21.249 DEBUG [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x38e99d68, L:/192.168.1.100:60744 - R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] Channel acquired, now 1 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2019-11-06 17:32:26.251  WARN [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0x38e99d68, L:/192.168.1.100:60744 - R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null

2019-11-06 17:32:26.255 DEBUG [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x38e99d68, L:/192.168.1.100:60744 ! R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] Releasing channel
2019-11-06 17:32:26.256 DEBUG [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x38e99d68, L:/192.168.1.100:60744 ! R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2019-11-06 17:32:32.592 DEBUG [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xdee3a211, L:/1192.168.1.100:60746 - R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] Channel acquired, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2019-11-06 17:32:37.597  WARN [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xdee3a211, L:/192.168.1.100:60746 - R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null

2019-11-06 17:32:37.600 DEBUG [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xdee3a211, L:/192.168.1.100:60746 ! R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] Releasing channel
2019-11-06 17:32:37.600 DEBUG [my-service,,,] 56942 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xdee3a211, L:/192.168.1.100:60746 ! R:elastic.internal.com/192.168.1.101:9200] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 0 inactive connections
```

Until eventually all the active / inactive connections have been cleaned and then it re-creates new connections which then work.

Is there a way to tune things behind the scenes, to limit how long a connection can remain in the pool for before being re-created? Or an alternative idea to be able to handle these timeouts.

Comment: Do https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-600 and/or https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-603 help?

Comment: Unfortunately I took a look and it doesn't look like it, it seems we need access to the underlying client to either tune the Connection Pool settings or to have it not use a pooled connection. Most likely due to how our elastic implementation is currently setup which we're trying to upgrade to be more compatible .